# How open ports in INPUT chain, only for a target IP, with iptables?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, ip

I have a server Debian 7 Wheezy, with 2 assigned IPs.
I have different service on different port assigned to the IPs. 
How can i set iptables rule, to work only with one of IP?

Example:
I Have 2 IPs: 192.168.1.234 and 192.168.1.235
I want open port 56 only for 192.168.1.234, which I want open port 80 only for 192.168.1.235.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- define default policy for the `INPUT` chain:

  `iptables -P INPUT DROP`
- allow connection to specific combinations of IP addresses and UDP/TCP ports (example with TCP):

  `iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.234 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 56 -j ACCEPT`
  `iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.1.235 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`
- any other traffic will be dropped as the default policy is `DROP` so it's a good practice to log it before the rules are put  into production to make sure that everything works as defined:

  `iptables -A INPUT -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Dropped: "`
- finally, you can remove this logging rule